# create directory in parent root with php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

my site is in `/var/www/mysite` directory .i use laravel and want to create directory in `/uploads` directory .so /uploads is besides of /var .

```
/var/www/mysite
/uploads
```

i set `0777` permission for `/uploads` but permission denied happened.
I try with this code

```
<?php mkdir('/uploads', 0777 , true) ; ?>
```

Comment: can you copy-paste the exact error?

Comment: When you says you set the permission for `/uploads` to `777`, doesn't that mean the directory already exists? And from your code it seems like you're trying to create the same directory again?

Comment: permission denied happen not directory exist .so i edit my code to <?php mkdir('/uploads/new', 0777 , true) ; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your web user (www-data, apache or whichever) is restricted by the operating system to use `/var/www`. You can't read,write,delete any files outside `/var/www`. So that's not a laravel issue.

Comment: but I can upload file to /upload folder

Comment: Yes if you had it created as root by console or whatever method you used. What you fail to see is that no one can create files in `/` except user `root`. You're trying to `<?php mkdir('/uploads', 0777 , true) ; ?>` as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Function that create all directories (folders) of given path. No need to write code create each directories (folders) of given path. it will create all directories (folders).

Like : If you want to create directory structure like 
**organizations / 1 / users / 1 /**

So you only need to call this function with directories path like 
**$directories_path = 'organizations/1/users/1/';

createUploadDirectories($directories_path);**

```
/*
* Method Name : createUploadDirectories
* Parameter : null
* Task : Loading view for create directries for upload
*/

if ( ! function_exists('createUploadDirectories')){
    function createUploadDirectories($upload_path=null){
        if($upload_path==null) return false;
        $upload_directories = explode('/',$upload_path);
        $createDirectory = array();
        foreach ($upload_directories as $upload_directory){
            $createDirectory[] = $upload_directory;
            $createDirectoryPath = implode('/',$createDirectory);
            if(!is_dir($createDirectoryPath)){
                $old = umask(0); 
                mkdir($createDirectoryPath,0777);// Create the folde if not exist and give permission
                umask($old); 
            }               
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Use File;
File::makeDirectory(base_path() . '/path/to/directory', 0775, true);
```

This will attempt to create /path if it doesn't exist. Then /path/to if it doesn't exist. And finally /path/to/directory if it doesn't exist. If all created directories are successfully created then true will be returned.

If you want to place the directory in your public path; use:

```
File::makeDirectory(public_path() . '/path/to/directory', 0775, true);
```

Source: [Laravel Recipes](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/147/creating-a-directory)